# Explode and implode

Tags: php

Can't get this to work! Argh. Now if I remove test.rar from /uploads I want to remove it from `$row['attachments']` but it just wont! Been scratching my head for a while now...

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$row['attachments'] = "angeleyes.jpg|test.rar"; // in reality i get this from the database
$attachments = explode('|', $row['attachments']);
$dir = "../uploads/";

if ($row['attachments']) {

    foreach($attachments as $file) {

        if(is_file($dir.$file))
            echo '<a href="#">'.$file.'</a> ('.filesize_formatted($dir.$file).') <br>';

        // If file wasnt found, clean up
        else {

            // Remove it
            $list_of_attachments = $row['attachments'] ? explode("|", $row['attachments']) : array();
            if(!in_array($file, $list_of_attachments)) $list_of_attachments[] = $file;
            $newstring = implode("|", $list_of_attachments);

            // lets see if it works
            var_dump($newstring);

             // update db
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You already have the array over on `$attachments`, just remove it for that array and then implode it at the end of the loop.

Comment: `in reality i get this from the database` Smells like a bad database design.

Comment: Yes, please [normalize your database schema](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your *else* statement :

```
$list_of_attachments = $row['attachments'] ? explode("|", $row['attachments']) : array();
```

First you already exploded *$row['attachments']* in *$attachments*.

Second, the code is reached only under the above condition :

```
if ($row['attachments'])
```

So this line looks useless. What do you intended to do with it ?

Then :

```
if(!in_array($file, $list_of_attachments)) $list_of_attachments[] = $file;
```

If *$file* does not exist on your hard drive but still exists in *$list_of_attachments* (which array is a duplicate of *$attachments*...), then you **add it** to *$list_of_attachments*. You never *remove it*, as far as I can see...

If you want to remove it, clean your code and may be try something like this :

```
// $row['attachments'] = "angeleyes.jpg|test.rar";
$attachments = explode('|', $row['attachments']);
$dir = "../uploads/";
$remove = array();
foreach ($attachments as $file) {
    if (is_file($dir . $file)) {
        /**
         * File exists : print
         */
        echo '<a href="#">' . $file . '</a> (' . filesize_formatted($dir . $file) . ') <br>';
    }
    else {
        /**
         * File does not exists : remove it from $attachments
         */
        $remove[] = $file;
    }
}
$attachments = array_diff($attachments, $remove);
// then update whatever...
```

[NB : untested code... don't copy/paste blindly...]

Answer (score 0):

The `!in_array($file, $list_of_attachments)` test is always false (since `$file` is taken from iterating over an array that's always equal to `$list_of_attachments`) Regardless of that, the most serious issue is that you're never removing the actual array element! The lines that claim to remove the file actually don't, since they take no steps to either remove the element from the array, or create a new array without it.

Not to mention that your current implementation would have to overwrite `$row['attachments']` while iterating over it, which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
(See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/L1w3ow)**.)

```
$row["attachments"] = "angeleyes.jpg|test.rar";
$attachments = explode("|", $row["attachments"]);
$newAttachments = array();
$dir = "../uploads/";

if ($row["attachments"]) {
    forEach ($attachments as $file) {
        if (is_file($dir . $file)) {
            echo('<a href="#">' . $file . '</a> ('
                 . filesize_formatted($dir . $file) . ') <br>');
            $newAttachments[] = $file;
        }
    }

    $newAttachments = implode("|", $newAttachments);
    if (strCaseCmp($row["attachments"], $newAttachments) != 0) {
        echo("You need to update the DB:");
        var_dump($newAttachments);
    } else {
        echo("No need to update !");
    }
}
```